# Close HTTP connection if authentication fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, denial-of-service

We are developing a rest application using spring boot framework and jetty server.

We want to prevent app from a rogue client to hit continuously without delay without appropriate authentication details.

What we want is : if a client without proper credentials tries to access application, spring security will determine authentication status. If authentication fails, either spring boot or jetty should close the HTTP connection.

So when next time the client sends a request, it has to go through the process of TCP handshaking again. It should not be able to hit the application continuously in the same connection.

But I am not able to find such property in jetty or spring boot.
Can anybody throw some light on how to achieve this or if this is valid requirement to keep.

Comment: How is the connection made towards your Spring Boot application? It it a REST API with a mobile or a Javascript client? Or are you using session login with server-side HTML templates?

Comment: rest api with any client. It could be postman or custom client. No session supported.

Comment: _It should not be able to hit the application continuously in the same connection._ -> You might want to google for "spring boot rate limiting" as well.

Comment: I could not find any thing concrete where spring boot framework helps in rate limiting. can you give any link.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box support so I can't give you a direct link, but there seem to be some libraries that do that, hence the tip to google for it. I have no experience with any library unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following header to the response when authentication fails to inform the upstream to close the connection:

```
Connection: close
```

This is a snippet from the rfc spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10)

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to
> signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
> response. For example,
>
> ```
>    Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that
> the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1)
> after the current request/response is complete.

Comment: in this we leave this choice up to client whether to use same connection or not.. some rogue client if connected, they will not do this

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way of achieving this other than sending the conenction close header in the response. If you are wanting to mitigate the risk of rogue clients performing a denial of service attack against your service, you may want to look into implementing a rate limiting solution.